# Javascript IDE/Debugging

Tags: javascript, debugging

I am finding myself doing more and more development using jQuery/Ajax/Javascript/JSON these days to handle tasks on the client side.

In doing all of this I am in a woeful state for debugging, particularly in that I don't have an output that shows me what JavaScript methods are being called and when.  Am I missing something simple here?

I am aware that I can put breakpoints in Google Chrome developer tools and also in IE and FF, but I don't know of any tool that will, say, allow me to hover over an HTML element and then show on an output screen that such-and-such hover event just occurred which fired so-and-so event within which event blah-blah-blah was posted to the server via ajax.

Comment: Maybe the Firebug JavaScript Debugger is what you are looking for: http://getfirebug.com/javascript

Comment: Thanks to you all!  The 'Visual Event' tool that Alex mentions below fits my need excellently, and FireQuery (see Geoff's answer below) looks promising as well.  Hat's off to you fellas.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event might help you

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the firebug plug in for Firefox?
http://getfirebug.com/

I've not used that much, but it may fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Install Firebug in Firefox and then add the [FireQuery](http://firequery.binaryage.com/) extension.  I don't think you'll get anything as detailed as you are asking, but this is pretty good.